# Storing and retrieving JSON in angular4

Tags: javascript, json

I have a scenario where there is a for loop, and in each iteration of for loop, a JSON object is obtained. Now I want to store all the obtained JSON objects in a single variable so that I can use it in other methods. Can you please provide me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
finalArray = [
    {
        var1: string,
        var2: number
    }
];

for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    finalArray.push({
        var1: jsonObj[i].var1,
        var2: jsonObj[i].var2
    });
```

Comment: You should add an explanation with your answer so the asker (and future readers) know not only how to fix the problem, but also why the problem was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is somewhat straight-forward, only you have to parse each new bit of JSON:

```
var json, item, items = [];
for(var i = 0; i < number_of_items; i++) { // your loop
    json = getNewPortion();  // obtained JSON (you can have whatever code that brings it)
    item = JSON.parse(json); // an object corresponding to that JSON
    items.push(item);        // store into our array
}
```

This way, you'll get a variable `items` which is an array. If you need JSON instead, use

```
var finalJSON = JSON.stringify(items);
```